# Can't make Youtube video in modal stop playing in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I have a set of modals that has a different youtube video in each. I've added code to reset the src of the video every time the modal is closed, but it will only work in Firefox, not in IE or Chrome. I've tried a few different codes, but I can only make it work in Firefox nomatter what I try.

JavaScript:

```
function close_modal(){  

    //hide the mask  
    $('#mask').fadeOut(500);  

    //hide modal window(s)  
    $('.modal_window').fadeOut(500);

    //enable scoll on main page
    $('body').removeClass('stop-scrolling')

    var video = $("#currentVideo").attr("src");
    $("#currentVideo").attr("src","");
    $("#currentVideo").attr("src",video);  

}  
function show_modal(modal_id){

    //disable scroll on main page
    $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling')  

    //set display to block and opacity to 0 so we can use fadeTo  
    $('#mask').css({ 'display' : 'block', opacity : 0});  

    //fade in the mask to opacity 0.8  
    $('#mask').fadeTo(500,0.8);  

     //show the modal window  
    $('#'+modal_id).fadeIn(500);  

}
```

Modal HTML:

```
<div id='jensVoigtModal' class='modal_window'>
    <h3>Jens Voigt</h3>
    <p>(born 17 September 1971) is a German professional road bicycle racer for UCI ProTeam Trek Factory Racing. Voigt is known for his propensity to attack, and for his positive racing attitude.<br />
    <br />
    He is capable of repeated attacking, holding a high tempo, and breaking away from the peloton. He has worn the yellow jersey of the Tour de France twice, though he has never challenged for the overall title due to his lack of ability in the mountains. In cycling folklore, he is considered as one of the best rouleur riders to this day.<br />
    <br />Voigt is generally popular with cycling fans, both for his aggressive riding style and his affable, forthright and articulate style in dealing with the public and media.<br />
        <center>
            <iframe id="currentVideo" width="600" height="338" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_Zeu4mPATpA?wmode=opaque&html5=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </center>
    <br />
    Read more about Jens Voigt on the Trek Factory Racing homepage: <a href="http://www.trekfactoryracing.com/team/riders/jens-voigt" id="pageLink" target="_blank">”Jens Voigt”</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it work in IE and Chrome without using the youtube api? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could try detaching the iframe from the dom and storing it in the modal's data structure.

Comment: Could you show me what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the youtube API

Change the original src of the iframe to

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/_Zeu4mPATpA?wmode=opaque&html5=1&rel=0&enablejsapi=1`

note the &enablejsapi=1 that i added to the end.

then in your script file add the call to the YouTube api below

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Create the player instance

this may look daunting but it is simple when you get your head around it.

```
var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('currentVideo', {

        });
      }
```

The var player is used to reference the Video functions.
and the currentVideo is the id of the iframe.

and finally you can stop the player using

```
player.stopVideo()
```

Okay it's still not quite as simple as it should be but it's probably the most reliable way

Comment: Because I don't quite understand it. I've tried adding your code, but now it doesn't work in any browser.